# How can I wrap the setPlaceholderText in a QPlainTextEdit field?

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

I have a somewhat lengthy placeholder text in the `QPlainTextEdit` field but it won't wrap around. Even though I set the `setWordWrapMode` attr to `WordWrap`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Here is a screenshot from what I get in Maya (2018):

[image]

The text should read `Comment on what you have done here, i.e.: what changes were made or new clothing...` but get cut off after "were". You kind of see the tip of the letters but thats it.

The following code works doesn't work in Maya:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("testing")

        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layout()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.notes_ql = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.notes_ql.setText('Notes: ')
        self.notes_ql.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.notes_pt = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.notes_pt.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.notes_pt.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.WidgetWidth)
        self.notes_pt.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.notes_pt.verticalScrollBar().minimum())
        self.notes_pt.setPlaceholderText('Comment on what you have done here, i.e.: what changes were made or new clothing...')


    def create_layout(self):
        notes_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        notes_layout.addWidget(self.notes_ql)
        notes_layout.addWidget(self.notes_pt)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.setSpacing(1)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 6)
        main_layout.addLayout(notes_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        test_dialog.close()  # pylint: disable=E0601
        test_dialog.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    test_dialog = TestDialog()
    test_dialog.show()
```

Replacing the `if __name__` statement with the code snippet below so it runs as a standalone app work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestDialog()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]. Your code does not reproduce the problem since using it I get https://i.imgur.com/oElXaVD.png

Comment: @eyllanesc added code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The code works in Maya 2020, but not 2019 or 2018. My guess is that there is a bug in Qt 5.6 (2018/2019) or Maya's PySide2 package that was fixed in Qt 5.12 (2020).

Unfortunately, this means there is likely no easy fix for earlier versions.